# `exit $rc` and `if ( $rc -eq 0) {exit 0}` do not have the same effect on `WIFEXITED`?

Tags: c++, bash, exit

I have a C++ program that launches a bash script that launches a java program.
The C++ program uses `WIFEXITED(status)` to evaluate the exit code of the bash script and outputs an error message if the `WIFEXITED(status)` evaluates to `false`.

*Edited in answer to chepner* :
<strike>Why do some of the bash scripts below print an error message (i.e. `WIFEXITED(status)==false`) and others not? They look equivalent to me.</strike>

```
java -Xmx256M -jar $JAR $@ > outputFile.out
exit $? 
#Prints an error code

java -Xmx256M -jar $JAR $@ > outputFile.out
rc=$?
exit $rc 
#Prints an error code

java -Xmx256M -jar $JAR $@ > outputFile.out
rc=$?
if [ $rc -eq 0 ]
then
   echo "succes"
   exit 0
else 
   echo "failure"
   exit $rc
fi
#Prints succes but also the error code

java -Xmx256M -jar $JAR $@ > outputFile.out
exit 0
#Does not print an error code
```

For information:
`echo $?` always prints a 0.
`echo $rc` also prints a 0.

Comment: Could this be because the java -jar command is successful in starting the jar file, even if the jar file fails to properly launch? That would not be an error of the java -jar command would it? In a sense the command is successful in launching the .jar application, but the application itself is not successful. The JAVA application could not be setting an error code itself, so `java -jar` thinks it was successful? Just my thoughts...

Comment: Perhaps this will give some insight. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/20573/why-does-java-exit-with-success-after-an-uncaught-exception

Comment: Your `if` statement is not valid `bash`; it should produce a syntax error.

Comment: Show your C++ code, seems like you are using `WIFEXITED` wrong.

Comment: @bluerojo (1) I read in some posts that `$?` takes the exit code of the java program (which BTW seems to execute properly). (2) Thanks for the link. It is indeed interesting but the behavior of the `echo $rc` vs `exit ?rc` is still bothering me.

Comment: @chepner You are right. Sorry for this really basic mistake, I have been coding in too many languages lately! And for some reason there was no error message. (Probably due to the call via the C++ program...) I corrected it and I now get the same error message from the C++ program as for the other codes... I edited my questions with the new results. But I am even more confused now...

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I think I got it now. The C++ code (third party) was just making very strange assumptions on the return value of the shellscript/java code and my mistake in the if statement somehow compensated for that. I am not sure how it worked exactly but I corrected it to be more general. Assuming that most scripts would not give a negative exist status when everything went well. Thanks to @Roman, chepner,  and bluerojo, your combined answers allowed me to solve this! (upvote)

Comment: No problem at all Prolix. I tested the $? status after running a java-jar on various ajva programs and I noticed that it does indeed report an exit status of 0 on a couple of them even when it errors out and fails to start up.